# CSS3 ::after pseudo selector is not working

Tags: css

As mentioned in the title, my css `::after` pseudo element isn't working. My code goes like this, have I done something wrong?

```
    span::after {
        content: '';
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #0000ff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px;
        left: -10px;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? What other style rules do you have? Have you use your browser's dev-tools and element inspector? If not, **why not**?

Comment: Pseudo elements are `display: inline` by default, you can't set height and width for inline elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `display:block;` for the pseudu element to work. Also try to change your position to absolute for top and left properties.